Pyodbc + azure function timer communication link error / TCP Provider
I'm getting very random
('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x68 (104) (SQLExecDirectW)')

 
('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

errors when trying to connect and execute a simple "select *" query to another SQL Server such as followed:
query = "SELECT * FROM ProjectModule_Project"
cursor.execute(query)   
columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
allRows = cursor.fetchall() 

The baffling part is that this only occurs sometime after deployment, meaning if I redeploy the Azure Function and trigger it then and there, it will work seamlessly.
But if left for a day or so for the timer to run on its own, this will happen, and all subsequent manual calls will also produce the same error until redeployment.
Appreciate if anyone can help or can point me in some directions.

@VivekVaibhavShandilya No, it just a simple python script with pyodbc deployed to azure

@VivekVaibhavShandilya Python 3.9

The communication error occurs because of the function app is being idle for long time. Use retries in the code which will only create new connection again, Below is my code which works for me without retries:
import logging as ri_lg
import azure.functions as func
import pyodbc as rith

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    ri_lg.info('Hello Rithwik Bojja, Execution Started')
    ri_usna = 'rithwik'
    r_passwd = 'test@123'
    ri_ser1 = 'rithwik.database.windows.net'
    db1 = 'rithwik'
    ri_th = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};Server={ri_ser1};Database={db1};Uid={ri_usna};Pwd={r_passwd};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
    with rith.connect(ri_th) as cho:
        with cho.cursor() as rit:
            rit.execute('SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM [dbo].[rith_cars];')
            var = rit.fetchone()
    print("Hello Rithwik Bojja the table is : ",var)
    ri_lg.info('Hello Rithwik Bojja, Azure Function is Executed')
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello Rithwik Bojja the table is: {var}", status_code=200)

Output:

For further refer SO-Thread1  and SO-Thread2
You can also use keepAlive as below, which keeps the connection alive
keep_alive = 100
ri_th = f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};Server={ri_ser1};Database={db1};Uid={ri_usna};Pwd={r_passwd};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;KeepAlive={keep_alive}"


